# How to remove RowNames and Column Names in Matrix in R

Tags: r

I have an output as

```
       VAR FREQ
  1     A   2 
  2     R   3
  3     B   4
```

I want to show result as

```
        A  2
        R  3
        B  4
```

Which means that i want to remove Column Names and Serial Number

The query i am using is

```
data.frame(sort(table(substr(read.csv('extra/name.csv')$value, 1, 1)),decreasing =TRUE))
```

Kindly help with some pointers

Comment: Based on the comments below, this is all about how the result is printed in the console, not about the properties of the object. I would recommend editing the question to make that clear. (Also, despite the "matrix" in your title, it seems you want this to work on a data frame.)

Comment: yes , it is mainly about how to print it. i am not able to Print it  as the way i want it to be . Also , I am open to changing it to Data frame or Matrix

Answer (score 3):

We can set `dimnames` to `NULL` assuming it is a `matrix` as mentioned in the post

```
dimnames(m1) <- NULL
```

If we need to `print`, this can be done with `cat` as @Gregor showed

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
cat(do.call(paste, c(d1, collapse='\n')), '\n')
#A 2
#R 3
#B 4
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c("A", "R", "B", "2", "3", "4"), .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(
c("1", "2", "3"), c("VAR", "FREQ")))
```

Comment: what is (m1) in this context?

Comment: `m1` is your matrix object

Comment: so how would i fit this in my query ?

Comment: Plus it is a data frame that i am saving the result into

Comment: @StutiGupta. A `data.frame` cannot have a NULL rowname or column name

Comment: as.matrix(sort(table(substr(read.csv('extra/name.csv')$value, 1, 1)),decreasing =TRUE),dimnames=NULL)
I ran this query  now my result is  
            [,1]
       A   2
       R   3
       B   4

I dont want anything else to come other than the letter and the count . not even [,1]

Comment: @StutiGupta In that case, you may need it as a `list` of `vector`s without any attributes.  Not clear why you need this format

Comment: can you help me on how to change the code for my original query.

Comment: @StutiGupta. Is this a `print`ing issue or something else?

Comment: @StutiGupta. I would not recommend this `d1 <- as.matrix(m1); colnames(d1) <- NULL;row.names(d1) <- NULL; print(d1)`. Note that the rownames should still print values as it is the default print method

Comment: No , I am trying different scenarios where i might get such sort of requirement

Comment: @StutiGupta. If you need a dataframe and to be printed differently, you may need to create a custom print method for data.frame

Comment: I tried this  d1 <- as.matrix(m1); colnames(d1) <- NULL;row.names(d1) <- NULL; print(d1)

Comment: But the  letters didnt print

Comment: @StutiGupta. Try this `cat(do.call(paste, c(d1, collapse='\n')), '\n')`

Answer (score 2):

`cat` can be used to print results to the console without the niceties added by `print`.

```
dd = read.table(text = "      VAR FREQ
  1     A   2 
  2     R   3
  3     B   4", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dd
#   VAR FREQ
# 1   A    2
# 2   R    3
# 3   B    4

for(i in 1:nrow(dd)) cat(unlist(dd[i, ]), "\n")
# A 2 
# R 3 
# B 4
```

Note that if your data has `factor`s, you will need to convert them to `character` to print like this. No guarantees are made about how columns of other classes will print (e.g., `Date` class). You also lose the justification and rounding done automatically by `print`.